# Change canvas background - metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, background, microsoft-metro

A note: I've just started approaching Windows 8 so, please be gentle. I want to set a background image to a canvas:

```
private void InsertImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var uri = new System.Uri("inkpen:///Assets/01.jpeg");
    var photo_background = new ImageBrush {
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage {
            UriSource = uri
        }
    };
panelcanvas.Background = photo_background;
}
```

**xaml:**

```
<Canvas Name="panelcanvas" Background="White" Margin="47.5,57,327.5,153"/>
```

The background changes from white to black and the image doesn't load. How can I fix this? 
Thank you.

Comment: What is `inkpen:///Assets/01.jpeg`?

Comment: the uri of the image. Is writed wrong?

Comment: You appear to have a `}` too much in your sample code.

Comment: I am not aware of a protocol named `inkpen`. I'd expect `c:` or `http://`.

Comment: I have copied the image into Assets folder. If I use "/Assets/01.jpeg" as Uri I get "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the Uri

```
ms-appx:///Assets/01.jpeg
```

fixed it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx